# HttpServlet and JSP integration

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm wondering is possible to integrate custom servlet logic with .jsp template view. For example I have the following servlet:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
      String name = "Mark";        
  }
}
```

and I want to place `name` variable inside jsp file(new.jsp) like:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>New</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <%= name %>

    </body>
</html>
```

My web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/new.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/new</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I don't want to put `name` in request.

Any help?

---

UPDATE

Great thanks, but I'm still having a trouble.
Firstly, I updated  my servlet:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
      String name = "Mark";
      request.setAttribute("name", name);
      request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/new.jsp").forward(request, response);       
  }

  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
      String name = "Mark";
      request.setAttribute("name", name);
      request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/new.jsp").forward(request, response);       
  }
}
```

I also changed my view:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>New</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         ${name}

    </body>
</html>
```

But when I use `${name}` there's nothing displayed. I thought that I should import any jstl, but unfortunately if I use `<%= request.getAttribute("name") %>` I'm getting `null`.

---

UPDATE 2
Finally solved! It was my fault, I forgot set

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>com.example.MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

Comment: Why can't you simply use `<% %>` tags for the code within the JSP?

Comment: @Kyte: that's discouraged as per JSP 2.0 coding conventions. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/code-convention-138726.html

Comment: Interesting. Good to know. (I admit I learned JSP/servlets caveman-style)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to implement the `doGet()` method instead. A normal HTTP request (clicking a link, a bookmark or entering the URL straight in browser address bar) defaults to `GET` method.

In order to make objects available in JSP in a preprocessing servlet, you need to set it as an attribute in request, session or application scope. Finally you need to forward the request/response to the JSP so that it can be displayed.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String name = "Mark";
    request.setAttribute("name", name);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/new.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

If you fix the servlet mapping as follows

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/new</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

then you can just invoke the servlet by http://localhost:8080/contextname/new. In the forwarded JSP you can access the `name` just by EL

```
${name}
```

Note that the JSP is placed in `/WEB-INF` folder in order to avoid direct access without the preprocessing servlet being called by entering the JSP URL in browser address bar instead.

#### See also:

- [Our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)
- [Our Expression Language wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)
- [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Comment: `${name}`, not `${requestScope.name}` ?

Comment: @ryan: if there's nothing in the page scope with the same attribute name, you can just omit the explicit scope declaration. The `JspContext#findAttribute()` scans in page, request, session and appliation scopes. See also our EL wiki page which is linked in bottom of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `name` as a request attribute and get it in the JSP.

For example, in your servlet, you can do:

```
request.setAttribute("name", name);
```

and get it using:

```
<%= request.getAttribute("name") %>
```

or better yet, use EL:

```
${requestScope.name}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to put "name" in the request, then the only way is to use scriptlet within the JSP code. This is not a clean or standards based solution though.

**REPEAT ## THIS IS NOT A CLEAN SOLUTION ## USE request to store the name as others have pointed out.**

So for example

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>New</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <% String name = "Mark" %> <%-- PUT THE name IN HERE --%>
         <%= name %>

    </body>
</html>
```

But what is the reason why you don't want to put name in the request? That was why servlets are there for.